Facebook API suddenly starts to fail with. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature
At midnight UTC on the 7th of June my facebook integration started returning:
((#100) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature.
When getting information about a page.
I can't see anything on the changelogs about something on this date, but I had a notice of deprecation of v13 for the 28th of May and the switch to v14.
Maybe this change was rolled out over time and my account got the change on the 7th of June?  I can't see anything relevant in the v14 changelog.
I am lost on what the issue is.
The Page token I am testing has 'pages_read_engagement' in its scope and my app also has 'Page Public Content Access'.
My own facebook page works though but users pages that appear to have the right permissions don't.
